# Can't take separate out put using two for loops in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

In the following program I used two double array list with two for loops and after the simple minus calculation take sum output. But this code don't give separate answer of sum as I expected.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test2forloop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double sum = 0;
        double x=0.;

        ArrayList<Double> arr1 =  new ArrayList<Double>();
        arr1.add(1.0);
        arr1.add(2.0);
        arr1.add(3.0);
        arr1.add(4.0);
        arr1.add(5.0);

        ArrayList<Double> arr2 = new ArrayList<Double>();
        arr2.add(6.0);
        arr2.add(7.0);

        for (int j = 0; j < arr1.size(); j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr2.size(); i++) {

           x= arr2.get(i) - arr1.get(j);
           sum=sum+x;  
        }
        System.out.println("sum="+sum);
        }
    }}
```

This program output is,

```
    sum=11.0
    sum=20.0
    sum=27.0
    sum=32.0
    sum=35.0
```

But I need output as,

```
    sum=11.0
    sum=9.0
    sum=7.0
    sum=5.0
    sum=3.0
```

What I need to do for taking this correct output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for (int j = 0; j < arr1.size(); j++) {
    sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr2.size(); i++) {

           x= arr2.get(i) - arr1.get(j);
           sum=sum+x;  
}
```

You need to initial `sum` to `0` before calculation.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double sum = 0.0;
        double x = 0.0;

        ArrayList<Double> arr1 = new ArrayList<Double>();
        arr1.add(1.0);
        arr1.add(2.0);
        arr1.add(3.0);
        arr1.add(4.0);
        arr1.add(5.0);

        ArrayList<Double> arr2 = new ArrayList<Double>();
        arr2.add(6.0);
        arr2.add(7.0);

        for (int j = 0; j < arr1.size(); j++) {
            sum = 0.0;
            for (int i = 0; i < arr2.size(); i++) {
                x = arr2.get(i) - arr1.get(j);
                sum += x;
            }
            System.out.println("sum=" + sum);
        }
    }
}
```